# Valgrind complains while working with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, valgrind

I have created 20 threads to read/write a shared file.I have synchronized threads.
Now My program works fine but when I run it with valgrind it gives me Errors like this:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:

   **definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
\
     **possibly lost: 624 bytes in 5 blocks.**

   **still reachable: 1,424 bytes in 5 blocks.****


    suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.

Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

Also When I press Ctrl + c , it gives the same errors.

I have not even malloced anything but still valgrind complains.

Any suggestion would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run valgrind --leak-check=full ./prog_name to make sure these reachable blocks are not something you can destroy in your program.  Many times initializing a library such as libcurl without closing or destroying it will cause leaks.  If it's not something you have control over, you can write a suppression file. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html section 4.4 has some info and a link to some examples

Answer (score 1):

Sill reachable blocks are probably caused by your standard library not freeing memory used in pools for standard containers ([see this faq](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports)): which would be a performance optimisation for program exit, since the memory is immediately going to be returned to the operating system anyway.

"Possibly lost" blocks are probably caused by the same thing.

The [Valgrind Manual page for memcheck](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks) has a good explanation about the different sorts of leaks detected.

Comment: So how can we get rid off these errors or I should merely compromise with them..............

Comment: If they are in your standard library then you can't. You can use `--leak-check=full` to show details of the still reachable blocks to check. You can use a suppression file (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) to hide details of errors that you don't care about.